# How to sum frequency by specific variables

Tags: r, date, time, sum

I've got a table of message frequencies, months and days as shown:

[image]

I'm trying to find a way in R to sum the freq column by the month and days of the week
So that the expected output would be:

March = 6, April = 33

Monday = 1, Tuesday = 12, Wednesday = 7, Thursday = 6, Friday = 12

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Months, Days) %>%
    summarise(Sum = sum(Freq, na.rm = TRUE))
```